# Any two level flip in $n$ qubit system

Tags: quantum-gate, circuit-construction

Let start with a multi controlled Toffoli gate. Looking at the matrix representation (in the binary base), you easily see 
$$
\pmatrix{
1& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0\\ 
0& 1& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0\\ 
0& 0& 1& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0\\ 
0& 0& 0& 1& 0& 0& 0& 0\\ 
0& 0& 0& 0& 1& 0& 0& 0\\ 
0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 1& 0& 0\\ 
0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 1\\ 
0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 1& 0\\ 
}
$$
that it only switches two states: $|111\rangle$ and $|110\rangle$. Conjugating with some $X$ gates on qubit 1 and 2 gives three more pair switches. Similar for the Fredkin gate which switches $|110\rangle$ and $|101\rangle$.

1. How to generate any of the $8\cdot 7 $ possible two level switches for three qubits out of elementary gates?
2. And how for general $n$?

For the three qubit case, I tried to e.g. construct a switch of $|000\rangle \leftrightarrow |111\rangle$ by mapping $|110\rangle \mapsto |000\rangle$. To achieve that I conjugated the Toffoli with the following sub circuit: 
two CNOTs conjugated by some $X$.

It worked! I could even construct a switch of $|000\rangle \leftrightarrow |011\rangle$ by extending the above subcircuit (with another Toffoli) the maps $|111\rangle \mapsto |011\rangle$.

But I'm not sure whether this approach is valid or if I had just a lucky punch...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conjugate by CNOTs to reduce to a case where the two states differ by exactly one bit, and conjugate by NOTs to make all the controls look for 1s instead of 0s.

1. Find a bit position `t` where the two states disagree about a bit. Let `s` be the state where the bit at `t` is 0.
2. For each bit position `p` other than `t` where the bit is 0 in `s`, apply a NOT to qubit `p`.
3. For each bit position `p` other than `t` where the two states disagree about a bit, apply a CNOT from qubit `t` to qubit `p`.
4. Apply a CCC...CNOT targeting qubit `t` controlled by all other qubits.
5. Do the same thing as in step (3).
6. Do the same thing as in step (2).

Comment: +1 thanks... $ $

Comment: How would that approach extend if a replace the $X=\pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}$ in the lower right (a two level swap) by a three cycle, e.g. $\pmatrix{1_n&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0}$..? The question would then be to create a generic three level swap...